# Looping through command line parameter options until next parameter

Tags: shell-script, zsh, options

In a new addition to a script I am working on, I want to loop through parameters associated with a flag until zsh reaches the next flag in the command. For instance, when the user enters the following:

```
datt -p Package1 Package2 Package3 --build
```

The script should take `Package1`, `Package2`, and `Package3` and assign these each to a place in an array. My thought process is to do something similar to this:

```
packages=()
for i in "$@"; do
     packages+=("$i")
done
```

My question becomes, then, how do I write the script in such a way that this loop keeps going until it hits the next flag on the command line? With the command shown at the beginning of my question (`datt -p Package1 Package2 Package3 --build`), how do I prevent the for loop from capturing `--build` as a package name and make it stop adding strings to the array after `PackageN`?

Comment: So "datt" is the name of the script? Would putting options before the subjects to be an option? I.e. `datt -p --build Package1 Package2 Package3'?

Comment: would all the non-option arguments always go the same array? Or does `-p` have something to do with it? The usual way would be to take options first, and non-options after, like Peregrino69 suggested above. That would be directly supported by e.g. `getopts`, though it only does short options.

Comment: @Karie I have removed the `bash` tag as your question explicitly mentions `zsh`. If the `bash` tag is warranted, please mention this in the question (and put the tag back in ;) ).

Answer (score 9):

Argument parsing can be annoying to get right. I would suggest you use [getopt(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt). From here you can specify the same flag multiple times:

```
datt -p Package1 -p Package2 -p Package3 --build
```

If for some reason you can't reuse the flag (not sure what that would be but...) you could also pass the arg as a single item and break on space:

```
datt -p "Package1 Package2 Package3" --build
```

Comment: The second option might work nicely, assuming I can put the full string into an area, breaking each value on the space and storing them as individual variables in the array. Is that possible?

Comment: Certainly possible, though you also have a couple good answers above, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, it'd be sanest to loop over all options in one loop, and drop the stuff in the right places there. Usually, I wouldn't do processing from the argument-parsing loop, but it might make sense if the order of options matters.

E.g. a loop like this (for Bash or zsh):

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
packages=()
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
    -p)      echo "p option seen...";;
    --build) echo "--build option seen after ${#packages[@]} packages...";;
    *)       echo "adding package '$1'";
             packages+=("$1");;
    esac
    shift;
done

typeset -p packages;
```

would give:

```
$ zsh dattest.sh -p foo bar doo --build
p option seen...
adding package 'foo'
adding package 'bar'
adding package 'doo'
--build option seen after 3 packages...
typeset -a packages=( foo bar doo )
```

Answer (score 5):

To do this kind of parsing, it's easier to use a while loop and `shift` until the array is empty.

```
packages=()
while (($#)); do
  case $1 in
    -p)
      while shift; [[ $1 != -* ]]; do
        packages+=($1)
      done
    …
  esac
  shift
done
```

You can use the `i` [subscript flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags) to perform the inner loop looking for the next option for you. `$array[(i)PATTERN]` is the index of the first element matching `PATTERN`, with indices starting at 1, so subtract 1 to get the number of elements left of that. If there is no match for `PATTERN`, the value is one plus the index of the last element, precisely so that code like this works in that case as well.

```
packages=()
while (($#)); do
  case $1 in
    -p) ((n = $@[(i)-*] - 1)); packages+=($@[1,$n]); shift $n;;
    …
  esac
  shift
done
```

---

The syntax you describe is non-standard. For this reason, I recommend against it: it's likely to confuse your users. Normally `datt -p Package1 Package2 Package3 --build` would do the same thing as `datt -p Package1 Package2 --build Package3`.